# Failed to restart AVAudioRecorder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudiorecorder

```c
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];

    self.recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"record.caf"]] settings:nil error:nil];
}

- (void)restartBtnPushed {  
    NSLog(@"Before stop: %d", self.recorder.recording);
    [self.recorder stop];
    NSLog(@"After stop: %d", self.recorder.recording);

    [self.recorder record];
    NSLog(@"After start: %d", self.recorder.recording);
}
```

If I keep hitting that RESTART button, I get results as below:

```
Before stop: 0
After stop:  0
After start: 1
--------------------
Before stop: 1
After stop:  0
After start: 1  <-----
-------------------- |
Before stop: 0  <----|----This is wrong version
After stop:  0
After start: 1  <-----
-------------------- |
Before stop: 1  <----|----This is correct version
After stop:  0
After start: 1
```

I can summarize it as below:

```
Stopped Recorder + 'stop' + 'start' -> Recorder is running successfully
Running Recorder + 'stop' + 'start' -> Recorder fails to run
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not sure it even makes sense to me :/ but, could it have to do with the runtime environment?  Just because you call start and stop on the recorder doesn't mean it actually starts or stops right then and there.  The main runtime thread controls the execution. (FOr all I know, the AV methods run in their own threads as well and if it is, maybe you are running into a race condition).  you might want to implement the AVAudiRecorderDelegate so you can verify that the recording did stop first before you restart it again.

Comment: @cabonbasednerd Thanks. Your answer is just what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to use the pause method rather than stop. If you refer to the method documentation for AVAudioRecorder stop will close the audio file, which seems to cause issues of overwriting the file the next time you want to start it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioRecorder/stop

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioRecorder/record

> Calling this method implicitly calls prepareToRecord, which creates (or erases) an audio file and prepares the system for recording.